# If you pay off a variable APR daily accruing credit card before the end of the month, is there interest?

Tags: credit-card, interest, compound-interest

Can you avoid 100% of interest on a card that accrues interest daily, by paying it off in full before the end of each billing cycle?

Comment: Depends on the card.

Comment: This question is too broad and an answer would be unduly long. The OP needs to ask a narrower question with more specification of details such as what does the balance consist of, what is paid, the current balance or the amount in the most recent statement, whether end of biling cycle means statement closing date or due date (which is earlier) than statement closing date, etc,

Comment: Lots (and I mean LOTS) of people pay no interest on their variable APR daily accruing credit cards by “just” paying the balance by the due date.

Answer (score 3):

**You need to ask your card provider or read the terms and conditions of the card.** Nobody can tell you what the terms for your particular card say.

Most cards do accrue interest daily, and most cards charge no interest if the balance is fully paid off by the due date every month. But yours may be different.